# c# newbie error variable but used as a method

Tags: c#

Please help as i am still new to c# and have no idea of how to fix this problem. i am trying to make a code for the taxes a person has to pay depending on his nationality. but whenever i try to run the code, the error "a is a variable but used as a method" came up.
 Another problem also occurred to me even when i deleted a completely is that kept on taking the thai condition even if i clearly stated for a khmer or viet condition ( person= khmer, person = viet)
 Thank you for your time

```
int a=0;
        bool person,khmer,viet,thai;
        khmer=true;
        thai = true;
        viet = true;
        person = khmer;


        String b;
        b= "";



        if (person == khmer)
        {
            a = 0;
            b="khmer";
        }
        if (person == viet)
        {
            a = 10;
            b = "viet";
        }
        if (person == thai)
        {
            a = 15;
            b = "thai";
        }


        else
        {
            a = 20;
            b = "alien";
        }
        Console.WriteLine("he pays " +a ("and he is from ")+b);
        Console.In.ReadLine();
```

Comment: better to use Select Case statement, instead of If command. That is faster than if

Comment: i'm sorry as i'm still new to c#, is there a way to fix this or work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line,

```
Console.WriteLine("he pays " +a ("and he is from ")+b);
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("he pays {0} and he is from {1}", a, b));
```

For your second problem, it's because they have the same value. In your code

```
bool person,khmer,viet,thai;
khmer=true;
thai = true;
viet = true;
person = khmer;
```

even if you change *person=khmer, person=thai or person=viet*. The value of person will always be **true**.

So in your if statement.

```
if (person == khmer)
        {
            a = 0;
            b="khmer";
        }
        if (person == viet)
        {
            a = 10;
            b = "viet";
        }
        if (person == thai)
        {
            a = 15;
            b = "thai";
        }
```

It will **always** enter the if bracket since their value is the same (true). Try changing thai,viet,kmer to integer or enum.

```
int person,khmer,viet,thai;
khmer = 1;
thai = 2;
viet = 3;
person = khmer;
```

Comment: ahh thank your sir but about my second problem, my code still is only accepting the thai condition, can you help me with this also please. thank you

Comment: It just looks cleaner that concatenating strings.

Comment: @RonaldEstacion Grant means that you can use [this Console.Writeline overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx) - it does the formatting for you, you don't have to call string.Format yourself.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yea, just looked though it on your first comment. Thanks for the info though

Answer (score 2):

In your final WriteLine, you do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("he pays " +a ("and he is from ")+b);
```

To the compiler, it looks like `a("and he is from ")` is a method call. You're "calling" `a` with a parameter of `"and he is from"`.

You just missed a `+`. It should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("he pays " + a + "and he is from " + b);
```

Or better, using the [string formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx) version of WriteLine:

```
Console.WriteLine("he pays {0} and he is from {1}", a, b);
```

Comment: ahh thank you. sorry making such a newbie mistake and taking your time.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second part of your question:

> Another problem also occurred to me even when i deleted a completely is that kept on taking the thai condition even if i clearly stated for a khmer or viet condition ( person= khmer, person = viet)

There are flaws in your logic.

You've hard-coded all nationalities to be `True`. And setting `person = khmer` really just sets `person = True`, which doesn't tell you much of anything later on in the code.

You end up running *every* `if` statement, so the final `if (person == thai)` wins out, and `a = 15` and `b = "thai"` *every time*.

You've got to change your code to accept parameters.

And I'd suggest replacing your strings and numbers with an enumeration representing nationalities.

```
// You can specify nationalities, and even assign each one the correct numerical value
public enum Nationality
{
    khmer = 0,
    viet = 10,
    thai = 15,
    alien = 20,
}

// Then in your method, just cast the selected nationality to an int to get the
//  numerical value, and call ToString() to get the name
private void ReportNationality(Nationality nationality)
{
    Console.WriteLine("he pays {0} and he is from {1}",
                      (int)nationality, nationality.ToString());

    Console.In.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a + here after "a"

```
 Console.WriteLine("he pays " +a  + ("and he is from ")+b);
```